# What kind of tenor will my voice lead me to (audio recording included)?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

Good evening All, I'm a 24 year old male who is very interested in operatic arts and how human voices work. I have just attended few voice lessons and have been classified as a tenor.

I have made two audio recordings of myself vocalizing several tones and would like to know, out of curiosity, if they are reinforced falsetto, head voice, or chest/mixed voice? (Apologies for my poor voice quality)

1.) https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151783829594058&l=917821361708559690

2.) https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151783829099058&l=3637408008140603908
(I'm not too sure what this note is, but it sounds like it's above Bb4)

The 3rd recording details my attempt to sing Che Faro senza before I attended any voice lessons and went through any warm up, so my high notes sound shaky. In fact, my G4 sounds fluttery and anything above that seems to be in a different register:

3.) https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151727800764058&l=236862807768213136

Based on the above two recordings, given proper training, what kind of tenor will I be?

Answer (score 4):

One cannot really tell where a voice type is heading, and it very much depends on what you end up being long-term comfortable with.

To give you an idea about different voice types, I just made a [recording showing the difference](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1n05ns_malevoicetypes_music) between chest voice, head voice, and falsetto over the same range.  It's not all that surprising that using chest voice and falsetto over the same octave range will be less than convincing at the respective upper and lower range.  The difference between chest and head voice is mostly apparent at the higher range where keeping locked in pure chest voice gets close to the voice flipping.  For reference, I add another copy of chest voice one octave below, and of falsetto one octave higher.

See whether this gives you more of an idea what this is about.  In the lower/middle range of the exhibited range, head voice is smoothest because the falsetto is really taken below its natural range.  In the low range, head voice is basically just the same as chest voice but with less chest resonance.  In the higher ranges, it moves into a mixed voice type.

Comment: wow. awesome video! it is hard to tell whether you are using falsetto or mixed voice from 1:01-1:03...

Comment: Imagine chest voice like a flap blown closed in one direction, falsetto in the other direction.  The larger the volume, the stronger the wind.  You can pull the flap with a bit of rubber band in either direction.  If you have good positioning, you can keep it in "mixed position" pretty well if done in time.  High pitches pull towards "falsetto" at an angle.  If you keep too long at "chest" position, the flap breaks open uncontrolledly eventually.  In the respective comfort ranges, mixed voice is little different from falsetto or chest voice, as opposed to the extreme ranges of the registers.

Comment: I see. Do professional operatic tenors sing the high notes in mixed voice ?

Comment: Anyways, I think you have a nice voice. I guess you are a baritone?

Comment: There is considerable variation depending on the underlying voice type (quite a few operatic tenors are natural baritones).  If we are talking about "Heldentenor" passages, high passages are typically "belted" in chest voice, possibly somewhat colored.  Lyrical tenors tend to employ head or mixed voice a lot more.  Either will avoid full falsetto (when you need full falsetto, you are basically outside of your Fach as a tenor).  Countertenors and male altos are a totally mixed bag, however.

Comment: I see. I guess I'm using mixed voice in my second recording?

Comment: I've been singing as a choir tenor for decades before getting voice lessons and getting unmasked as a bass-baritone.  I decided to focus on the falsetto and with a lot of practice sang as choir alto for a few years, then as countertenor in small music ensembles and as high tenor in male choirs.  But I've let the mixed choir alto range slide.  Nowadays my main style is stuff like Chanson, Klezmer, Folk more in the contralto range.  But it's been some time since I actually put on drag (otherwise, the audience is all "why are you singing like that?") and went on stage.

Comment: wow. so you could sing countertenor, tenor and bass-baritone! that's amazing!

Comment: No, that second recording is not mixed voice.  It's basically chest voice.  Mixed voice is not really accessible to beginners.  Basically when you sing scales starting in chest voice and ending in falsetto and (harder) back down with a sliding change in character, the transition is mixed voice.  In the recording you referenced, you are already beyond the "point of no return" regarding both pitch and volume: any change to falsetto (which you use in your first recording) would turn out to be a hard "yodeling" kind of flip.

Comment: Thanks for your observation! I have just checked against the electric keyboard and it turns out that the note in second recording is F#5.  I thought it is physically impossible for most adult males to access that note in chest voice so I have perceived that I might be unconsciously using mixed voice? Also, when I descend from that high note to around Ab4/G4, my voice seem to experience some form of break and it can be difficult to stay in pitch when I tried to further descend.

Comment: Actually, regular (mixed choir) tenor is what I stopped doing because it became too unhealthy: to stay "in style" with the others, I tended to stick around too much with chest voice.  Nowadays, I'd just sing through the break, but that makes it sit a lot in central passages.  And the "alto habit" of just dragging down the falsetto into the raspy range does not mix all too well with other tenors.  With regard to bass: while the falsetto singing improves the bass sound quality, engaging full chest voice quickly impacts the purity of the higher falsetto.  So one needs to decide what to aim for.

Comment: Mixed voice does not break.  The larynx has two basic muscle groups working on the vocal chord configuration and stretching/tensing them.  One does chest voice, the other falsetto.  You can employ both at once even while more or less stuck in one configuration, modifying its character.  With less control and practice, you get more possibilities :)  If you take a look at your third recording, you basically choke into your high notes.  It would be my guess that that's basically what you do in the second recording (larynx high).  That's a degree of freedom a practiced singer has learnt to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It seems that G4-A4 is the ''problematic part'' of my voice, i.e. I tend to sound flutterly/shouty there and  beyond that my voice would sound similar like that in the second recording. I guess (correct)practice makes perfect! So what explains the break in my voice?

Comment: Well, there are more muscles groups involved in and around the larynx, so you have some more possibilities for breaks.  With regard to high pitches: the vocal folds are muscles affixed to points of the larynx, and the larynx is cartilege.  And for the male voice, it's comparatively large, and it takes decades to "ossify", fully harden.  What happens if you try drawing taut strong rubberbands with a cardboard mechanism?  There are several opportunities for things not moving smoothly or even getting damaged.  Which is good reason not to go overboard with high powered singing too soon.